# Vscode extension: how to implement a hover function to add arguments to commands, e.g., to run search command with query

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to develop a custom button in vscode hover function. Meaning if I click the shortcut button, it will go to search sidebar and have a specific query search. Refer to the two images which is uploaded.

[image: Hover Search Button]

[image: Result Sidebar change]

In vscode command form, the extension code will look like this. (This works well except it requires to run from command pallete)

```
let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('test-hover.helloWorldSearch', () => {
    var word = "i_want_to_search";
    const searchOptions = {
        query: word,
    };
    vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.findInFiles', searchOptions);
});
context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
```

After that I convert into hover by using vscode.languages.registerHoverProvider, and the code look like this:

```
     let disposable1 = vscode.languages.registerHoverProvider('javascript', {
     provideHover(document, position, token) {
            var word = "i_want_to_search";
            const searchOptions = {
                query: word,
            };
            const commentCommandUri = vscode.Uri.parse(`command:workbench.action.findInFiles`);
            const contents = new vscode.MarkdownString(`[Search String](${commentCommandUri})`);
            contents.isTrusted = true;
            return new vscode.Hover(contents);
        }
    });
    context.subscriptions.push(disposable1);
```

This code is able to navigate the sidebar to search In file BUT without any query seacrh.
**The problem is,** I can't pass "searchOptions" to the command if I am using "vscode.Uri.parse". Is there any other way to do the same action as the above code but able to pass the searchOption? I have tried to search many different examples in the internet but most only come out to run command without searchOption.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The arguments to your command have to be appended as an encoded string, as shown in [command-uris](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/command#command-uris).

```js
const searchCommandUri = vscode.Uri.parse(
    `command:workbench.action.findInFiles?${encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(searchOptions))}`
);

const contents = new vscode.MarkdownString(`[Search String](${searchCommandUri})`);
```

If you wanted to get the word that you are hovering over, try this code:

```js
const word = document.getText(document.getWordRangeAtPosition(position));
```

Now your "Search String" hover button will search the word that is being hovered over.

Then change the text: "Search String" to the actual word you will be searching for:

```js
const contents = new vscode.MarkdownString(`[Search: ${word}](${searchCommandUri})`);
```

[image: hover with a search button demo]

Comment: Great..... I just tried this solution, it works... thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome, I learned something new and interesting from answering this.  Thanks for posting the question.   Are you going to use either of the additional tips abouts getting the word being hovered over or modifying the button text?

Comment: Its more of a QOL thing, I plan on making shortcuts for popular word searches (includes the word that is hovered) when I hover thru a word because I realize that I literally search thru a lot when reading other people's code (code review, bug fixes). So instead of highlighting the word or double clicking it - copy - go sidebar - paste... I just create one button to do it.... Anyway thanks a lot..