# In my VS Code extension, how to add gutter icon with action?

Tags: icons, vscode-extensions, gutter

I'm working on VSCode extension and need to add actions to gutter icons. Right now I'm adding gutter icon

```
    const documentDecorationType = vscode.window.createTextEditorDecorationType({
        gutterIconPath: context.asAbsolutePath('media/link.svg')
    });
    
    editor.setDecorations(documentDecorationType, [
        {   
            range: new vscode.Range(new vscode.Position(document.start_line, 0), new vscode.Position(document.end_line, 0)),
        }               
    ]);
```

How can I add an action/command to icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you can add a command directly to a gutter icon.  See [OnClick event on Gutter](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/5455) and [Allow clicking gutter icon](https://github.com/microsoft/codetour/issues/131): both issues are still open.

You may be able to add it as a command in a hover though (still trying to get it to work...)

Comment: "(still trying to get it to work...)"

Did you ever get this to work?

Comment: @vveil Not specifically for a gutter icon hover - I don't think there is any way to implement that.  But do you mean a hover over text with a command link in that hover, then yes.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68887679/836330.

Comment: I was actually looking for a way to implement a hover effect on a gutter icon, but I guess I have to think about another option then. Thanks for your help.